# How to get webcam pics to our site from a Astak Mole via email

Tags: email, webcam

Basically we have an Astak Mole cam that can email images at regular intervals and we want to put the images in a folder and post it on the site.

Is there a way to use IFTTT.com

We can control the email address that receives the message and the server that will display the image.

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about IFTTT.com but there are many ways to programatically get emails to a web server.

I wrote a [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/) with the three main methods for programmatically accessing email. These are namely:

- Setup an email server and have it run a script locally when an email arrives
- Poll over POP3 or IMAP to an existing email mailbox and then download the messages
- Use a third party (such as [CloudMailin](http://docs.cloudmailin.com)) that takes an email and forwards it as an HTTP Post to your website.

Any of these methods should allow you to do what you're asking, the option to choose is really about how much you need to scale or what you have available already.